# Let $f$ be a twice-differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f''$ is continuous. Prove that $f(x) f''(x) < 0$ cannot hold for all $x.$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a twice-differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f''$ is continuous. Prove that
$f(x) f''(x) < 0$ cannot hold for all $x.$

I have been able to think of specific examples of $f(x)$ in which $f(x)f''(x) <0$ does not hold, but I have not been able to come up with specific values of $x$ for which $f(x)f''(x)<0$ does not hold.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Re your question: Such a function would be strictly positive and strictly concave, or strictly negative and strictly convex. Does that help?

Comment: A follow up : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221908/functions-where-ffk0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume wlog that $f''(0)>0$. Then $f(0)<0$ and as neither factor can change sign,  $f''(x)>0>f(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$ and $f$ is strictly convex. Pick $a<b$ with $f(a)\ne f(b)$. Then the line through $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ intersects the $x$-axis. By convexity, $f$ is above this line outside $[a,b]$, hence must assume positive values.

Comment: Do you mind explaining to me why is f strictly convex if f''(x)>0>f(x)? Couldn't f be concave?

Comment: @rksrcl a twice differential function is convex iff its second derivative is non-negative. You have concavein the case not covered by my initial "wlog", in whic case we can consider $-f$ instead of $f$ (as $(-f)(-f'')=ff''$)

Answer (score 3):

Sketch of a proof. Details remain to be filled. The devil is in the details of course, but the idea should work.

1. Since f is continuous, it must be $f>0$ or $f<0$ everywhere (why?). wlog consider $f>0$. The hypothesis then implies $f''<0$ everywhere.
2. Now $f$ cannot be constant, therefore there must be $x_0$ where $f'(x_0) \ne 0$
3. Consider the case $f'(x_0)<0$. Prove that the function must remain below the straght line $y=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ for $x>x_0$. This implies that at a certain point $f(x)$ must change sign and become negative. Contradiction.
4. If $f'(x_0)>0$ make a similar argument for $x<x_0$

Comment: Could you please explain the first point a little more? I get that if f>0, f''<0 must be true for the inequality to hold, but how do we know f>0 or f<0 everywhere is possible? Couldn't f>0 be true for some x while f<0 for some other x, so long as f''<0 when f>0 and f''>0 when f<0?

Comment: Sure. This is a consequence of continuity alone (no other hypothesis). If a continuous function f(x) acquires values y_1 and y_2, than it must acquire all possible values between y_1 and y_2 . Have a look here maybe:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem . Using this, if the function is continuous and obtains positive and negative values, it must also have a zero somewhere.

Comment: And to be super clear, the function cannot have a zero by hypothesis otherwise f(x)=0 would make the inequality false.