# Functions where $ff^{(k)}<0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

This is a follow up on [Let $f$ be a twice-differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f''$ is continuous. Prove that $f(x) f''(x) < 0$ cannot hold for all $x.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221545/let-f-be-a-twice-differentiable-function-on-mathbbr-such-that-f-is-co/4221554#4221554) , for whoever is interested.

Trying to generalize the linked question, we can ask for which $k$ the following proposition is true:

Prop: Fix $k\ge 1$. There is no real function $f$ (where the derivatives make sense) such that $f(x)f^{(k)}(x)<0$ for every $x$.

Prop is true for $k=2$ (see link for proofs).

Prop is false for $k$ odd. Take $f(x)=e^{-x}$ as a counterexample.

What about the other even values of $k$ ?

Comment: Without loss of generality, $f^{(k)}>0$ for all x. This implies that $f^{(k-1)}$ is strictly monotone, in particular there exist $a<b$ such that $f^{(k-1)}(x)\geq b$ for x large enough and $f^{(k-1)}(x)\leq a$ for x negative enough. This implies (integrating) that there exist $c,d$ such that $f^{(k-2)}(x)\geq bx+d$ for x large enough and $f^{(k-2)}(x)\geq ax+c$ for x negative enough. This implies that there exist $e,f$ such that $f^{(k-3)}(x)\geq bx^2/2+dx+f$ for x large enough and $f^{(k-3)}(x)\leq ax^2/2+cx+e$ for x negative enough. And so on… This should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no $k$-times differentiable function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(x)f^{(k)}(x)<0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ if $k$ is a positive even integer.

Assume on the contrary that $f$ is such a function. Without loss of generality we can assume that $f(x) > 0$ and $f^{(k)}(x)<0$ for all $x$. Choose $x_0$ with $f^{(k-1)}(x_0) \ne 0$. From Taylor's theorem we get
$$
 0 < f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!} f^{(n)}(x_0) + \frac{(x-x_0)^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(\xi) \le \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!} f^{(n)}(x_0) \,.
$$
for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

This is a contradiction because the right-hand side is a polynomial of odd degree with a non-zero leading coefficient and approaches $-\infty$ for $x \to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$, depending on the sign of $f^{(k-1)}(x_0)$.

Comment: Ok this was really fast :D, nice application of the explicit form of the reminder in Taylor formula !

Comment: I like a lot actually this application, because it applies Taylor theorem not in a local fashion as I've mostly seen, but in a "global" one  thanks to the explicit form of the reminder :) . It sound instructive, or at least it looks very nice to me, for my limited experience  :)

Comment: @Thomas: Note that this is the immediate generalization of your proof to the other question: For $k=2$ we get $f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + f''(\xi)(x-x_0)^2/2  \le f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$.

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing it out :)